# Swift: Change the texture of a Sprite Kit object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

how can i change the texture of a SpriteKit object if a variable changes their value.

Something like:

```
    var x = 2
    if x == 1 {sprite has texture1}
    else if x == 2 {sprite has texture2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
if x == 1 {
    sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image1")
} else if x == 2 {
    sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image2")
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is a property then you can use a **property observer** like this

```
class Hero: SKSpriteNode {

    var x: Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            switch x {
            case 1: self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "texture1")
            case 2: self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "texture2")
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```